# Validate Shopping cart rule with custom from and to date EE 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, ee-1.14

I have created **custom from and to dates to validate the shopping cart rule coupons**.
For this I have overridden the Mage_SalesRule_Model_Mysql4_Rule_Collection setValidationFilter().

```
protected function setValidationFilter($websiteId, $customerGroupId, $couponCode='', $now=null)
{
    if ($this->getFlag('validation_filter')) {
        return $this;
    }        

    if ($couponCode)
        $couponCode = explode(',', $couponCode); // multiple coupon compatibility

    $this->getSelect()->reset();

    $this->getSelect()->from(array('main_table' => $this->getTable('salesrule/rule')));        
    //$this->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
    $this->addWebsiteGroupDateFilter($websiteId, $customerGroupId, $now);

    if ($couponCode) {
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('c' => $this->getTable('salesrule/coupon')), 
            'main_table.rule_id = c.rule_id ', 
            array('code')
        ); 

        // Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON is not defined
        $this->getSelect()->where(
            $this->getSelect()->getAdapter()->quoteInto(' main_table.coupon_type = ?', 1)
            .
            $this->getSelect()->getAdapter()->quoteInto(' OR c.code IN(?)', $couponCode)
        );

        //modify rule date to validate with custom dates
        if (is_null($now)) {
            $now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
        }

        $this->getSelect()->join(array('cd' => $this->getTable('couponenhancement/couponenhancement')), 
                'main_table.rule_id = cd.rule_id ', 
                array('cd.coupon_valid_from','cd.coupon_valid_to')
            ); 

        $this->getSelect()->where('cd.coupon_valid_from is null or cd.coupon_valid_from<=?', $now);
        $this->getSelect()->where('cd.coupon_valid_to is null or cd.coupon_valid_to>=?', $now);
        //ends          

        $this->getSelect()->group('main_table.rule_id');
    } 
    else {
        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.coupon_type = ?', 1);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->order('sort_order'); 

    $this->setFlag('validation_filter', true);

    return $this;
}
```

Printing the query gives me this..

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `c`.`code`, `cd`.`coupon_valid_from`, `cd`.`coupon_valid_to` FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` 
 INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids` ON main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `salesrule_coupon` AS `c` ON main_table.rule_id = c.rule_id 
 INNER JOIN `couponenhancement` AS `cd` ON main_table.rule_id = cd.rule_id  
 WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `salesrule_website` AS `website` 
 WHERE (website.website_id IN ('3')) 
 AND (main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id))) 
 AND (**from_date** is null or from_date = '2015-03-09') 
 AND (is_active = '1') 
 AND ( main_table.coupon_type = 1 OR c.code IN('APRGE05-2687-3459')) 
 AND (cd.coupon_valid_from is null or cd.coupon_valid_from='2015-03-09') 
 GROUP BY `main_table`.`rule_id` ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC
```

**PROBLEM HERE IS** the query also includes the default date columns(from_date & to_date) as well as My custom column for dates (coupon_valid_from & coupon_valid_to).

Now I need to Remove ONLY the default date columns **from_date & to_date** from the query. and my validation will work fine.

Is there a way to do it. `$this->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)` removed full where condition.. but I only need to remove those particular from_date and to_date where fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with `$select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)` and remove the field you don't want, add the reset again.